# Alternativa3D: Actionscript3: How to avoid z-fighting in imported 3DS model?

Tags: actionscript-3, mesh, overlapping, 3d-engine, decal

I can't seem to find a specific solution for my problem so I hope someone here can help me.

I am experimenting with **alternativa 3D** in Actionscript3 and I managed to upload a textured **.3DS** model from 3D Max.
The object is a complex spaceship that wasn't intended to be used in a game but I wanted to use it as an example.

**The problem is:**
Since the imported model is complex it has a lot of overlapping parts. Alternativa z-sorting engine don't react well to this overlapping and the output is jittery texture(i don't know how else to call it) in the overlapping places.

I know next time to model my objects with as less overlapping parts as possible but I am sure this problem will reappear in other forms in the future.

The Alternativa documentation suggests using **Decal** objects instead of Mash objects but I can't seem to convert imported object Mashs to Decay objects.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What near/far clipping distances do you use?
 And could you post a screenshot?

Though if by 'overlapping parts' you mean same what Mick said, there   is probably not much you can do besides fixing the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model where faces directly intersect one another, then I'd suggest this, not the engine, is the problem.

A well-built 3d model shouldn't have any intersecting faces - you may not notice or think it's a problem in a program like 3dsMAX, you can get away with it more - but it'll certainly show up in a real-time engine.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I fully agree with what you suggested, but never the less alternativa z-sorting is cuasing me trouble even if the parts are not overlapping but only very close (or at least so it seams to me).

Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the model and the output. I think it'll be a problem with the model, not the engine, but it won't take you very long to set up an Away3D working environment, give it a try in that - if it does the same (which I'm pretty sure it will) you know it's the mesh you're using.

Personally, I always model from scratch if I'm intending to use it in a realtime environment, models built for High-Q renders are often too complex, or sloppy in the manner of our discussion, to be much use.